# Loop over environment variables in POSIX sh

Tags: unix, environment-variables, sh

I need to loop over environment variables and get their names and values in POSIX sh (not bash). This is what I have so far.

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh

# Loop over each line from the env command
while read -r line; do
  # Get the string before = (the var name)
  name="${line%=*}"
  eval value="\$$name"

  echo "name: ${name}, value: ${value}"
done <<EOF
$(env)
EOF
```

It works most of the time, except when an environment variable contains a newline. I need it to work in that case.

*I am aware of the `-0` flag for `env` that separates variables with nul instead of newlines, but if I use that flag, how do I loop over each variable?* **Edit**: @chepner pointed out that POSIX env doesn't support `-0`, so that's out.

Any solution that uses portable linux utilities is good as long as it works in POSIX sh.

Comment: Assuming `POSIX` `env` produces a `\0` separated output as you need, how do you intend to parse using your script, `POSIX` `read` does not support de-lmiter `-d` nor `-0` is supported by `xargs`

Comment: In general, you can't even assume that `name` is a valid variable name. Run `env "foo bar=3"` and examine the output.

Comment: POSIX `env` does not support `-0` anyway.

Comment: @chepner Interesting about the invalid variable name. Ideally then, the solution would check if something is a valid variable (or get the names a different way). Also, I edited my question to address my mistake with the `-0` flag.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way to parse the output of `env` with complete confidence; consider this output:

```
bar=3
baz=9
```

I can produce that with two different environments:

```
$ env -i "bar=3" "baz=9"
bar=3
baz=9
$ env -i "bar=3
> baz=9"
bar=3
baz=9
```

Is that two environment variables, `bar` and `baz`, with simple numeric values, or is it one variable `bar` with the value `$'3\nbaz=9'` (to use `bash`'s ANSI quoting style)?

---

You can safely access the environment with POSIX `awk`, however, using the `ENVIRON` array. For example:

```
awk 'END { for (name in ENVIRON) {
            print "Name is "name;
            print "Value is "ENVIRON[name];
           }
         }' < /dev/null
```

With this command, you can distinguish between the two environments mentioned above.

```
$ env -i "bar=3" "baz=9" awk 'END { for (name in ENVIRON) { print "Name is "name; print "Value is "ENVIRON[name]; }}' < /dev/null
Name is baz
Value is 9
Name is bar
Value is 3
$ env -i "bar=3
> baz=9" awk 'END { for (name in ENVIRON) { print "Name is "name; print "Value is "ENVIRON[name]; }}' < /dev/null
Name is bar
Value is 3
baz=9
```

Comment: Your solution works in the sense that it will iterate over the variables without confusion caused by newlines, but if you want to parse the output of `awk` to do something other than printing on the terminal, you still have the same problem (having to guess based on the beginning of each line).  Is there a way to have `awk` output in a format that would guarantee it could be parsed without ambiguity?

Comment: I don't suggest parsing the output of `awk` (or language X); I would do whatever it is that is needed *in* `awk` (or language X). The only way to avoid ambiguity is to use a structured language like XML, JSON, YAML, etc, and then you've got two problems: generating the output in the first place, and parsing *it* once you've got it. Neither of these is particular strength of tools defined by POSIX.

Comment: I am often surprised how often awk/sed solutions are presented (and accepted) as "shell" solutions, while actually being different programming languages.  These tools are largely supported, no doubt, and usually available to whoever works with the shell.  But they still remain external to the shell, and if you cannot reliably parse the output of a tool in the shell, then you lose a bit of the "everything as a file + have fun with pipes" philosophy that got sed/awk practically considered "shell syntax" to begin with.  Oh! well...

Comment: "Any solution that uses portable linux utilities is good as long as it works in POSIX sh." There is nothing wrong with using external utilities *when they are warranted*, as they are here.

Comment: It was not really meant as criticism of your proposed solution or a comment specific to the OP question, just a general thought  Your solution provides something the shell alone cannot, so it is certainly pertinent in the context.

Comment: I'm accepting this solution since it solves the problem and its edge cases. I'm still open to a solution that uses sh without another language, but it seems it might not be possible within the constraints. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this would work?

```
#!/usr/bin/env sh
env | while IFS= read -r line
do
  name="${line%%=*}"
  indirect_presence="$(eval echo "\${$name+x}")"
  [ -z "$name" ] || [ -z "$indirect_presence" ] || echo "name:$name, value:$(eval echo "\$$name")"
done
```

It is not bullet-proof, as if the value of a variable with a newline happens to have a line beginning that looks like an assignment, it could be somewhat confused.

The expansion uses `%%` to remove the longest match, so if a line contains several `=` signs, they should all be removed to leave only the variable name from the beginning of the line.

Comment: Indirect parameter expansion is a `bash` extension, not supported by POSIX.

Comment: @chepner I have modified my answer.  Do you see anything wrong now?

Comment: The question asks for a solution that handles values containing newlines; this does not. There is no way to do that using the output of `env`; see my answer for an example.

Comment: @chepner  I think you have not looked at my code completely.  It handles newlines in values, because the value is re-read from the variable, not parsed from the output of `env`.  Maybe this has some other drawbacks, but values with newlines work, I checked.

Comment: True; I'll rescind the downvote given that you do mention the caveat, but I don't think this is a good approach.

Comment: @chepner  It is not a perfect solution, to be sure, but understanding its limits, and depending on the need, it could be "good enough", by which I mean having predictable failure modes with benign side effects.  I would live with the limitations if I just want to debug a script or perform some kind of logging, I wouldn't it the risk were the loss of data of any value.

Comment: Thanks! This may be as close as you can get within the constraints of POSIX without another language. It gets a vote.

Answer (score 0):

Here an example based on the awk approach:

```
#!/bin/sh
for NAME in $(awk "END { for (name in ENVIRON) { print name; }}" < /dev/null)
do
  VAL="$(awk "END { printf ENVIRON[\"$NAME\"]; }" < /dev/null)"

  echo "$NAME=$VAL"
done
```

Comment: According to shellcheck (SC2013) one should replace the `for` loop with `while`. This would change your first line to: `awk "END { for (name in ENVIRON) { print name; }}" < /dev/null | while IFS= read -r NAME`